# R's FDA fourier() function - How Does it Work?

Tags: r, time-series, fft, curve-fitting

I was looking for a simple way to perform Fourier analysis of a time-series. The function `fourier()` in R's FDA package seems to be what I want, but I cannot figure out its inner workings.
Here is a simple example:

```
maxTime <- 10
omega <- (2*pi)/1
time <- seq(0, maxTime, maxTime/200)
signal <- 5*cos(omega*time)
# 
library(fda)
fit <- fourier(signal, 2)
#
summary(fit)

   const             sin1              cos1        
 Min.   :0.3162   Min.   :-0.4303   Min.   :-0.4472  
 1st Qu.:0.3162   1st Qu.:-0.2525   1st Qu.:-0.4419  
 Median :0.3162   Median : 0.0000   Median :-0.3691  
 Mean   :0.3162   Mean   : 0.0000   Mean   :-0.1376  
 3rd Qu.:0.3162   3rd Qu.: 0.2525   3rd Qu.: 0.2525  
 Max.   :0.3162   Max.   : 0.4303   Max.   : 0.4472
```

I would like to know, how are the values above computed?
The package documentation does not explain it; anyone knows?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the function itself? https://rdrr.io/cran/fda/src/R/fourier.R

Comment: Well, I learnt that FDA's `fourier()` in fact may not be what I want, even from a flippant reply.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I wrote an answer and deleted it as I found it not "genuinely" my effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of the function: Note that this was last modified in 2007(https://github.com/cran/fda/blob/master/R/fourier.R) so a newer documentation might be more accurate or better studying the function itself might provide more information.

> Computes the NDERIV derivative of the Fourier series basis
>     for NBASIS functions with period PERIOD, these being evaluated
>     at values in vector X
>
> Returns an N by NBASIS matrix of function values
>
> Note:  The number of basis functions always odd.  If the argument
>     NBASIS is even, it is increased by one.